# Clojure/leiningen cannot find dependencies

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am new to Clojure and Leiningen. Just started working on an existing project. I pull the repo and did the command Lein run. It complained:

"Could not find artifact arctype:service.jose:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not transfer artifact arctype:service.jose:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to enonic (https://repo.enonic.com/public/): Failed to transfer file https://repo.enonic.com/public/arctype/service.jose/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/service.jose-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with status code 409"

What I proceeded to do, under the assumption that the dependencies are bad, is that I went on repo.clojars.org. Manually looked into the dependencies and changed "[arctype/service.jose "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" :exclusions [arctype/service]]" in project.clj to "[arctype/service "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT":exclusions [arctype/service]]", because that is what it has on the site. But turns out that "Jose" is not inside of arctype/service, and changing the dependencies like I did removed it, so I have to change it back.

What im really confused about, is that, according to the error message, I went on repo.clojars.org to look for the dependencies I want, "arctype.service.jose" is no where to be found. Not even something close.

I saw the second half error message that mentions repo.enonic.com/public , so I try to look for the dependecy there as well. Same result, nothing. In my project.clj file, the repository is repo.enonic.com/public. I am really confused, can somebody please enlighten me! Thanks in advance!

Im not sure if I provided enough, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Most open source projects written in Java publish artifacts on Maven Central, and most Clojure projects publish artifacts on Maven Central or clojars.org.  The fact that your error message mentions https://repo.enonic.com/public/ might be because the artifact mentioned in your project.clj file was published on that server, not on clojars.org.

If I go to clojars.org (not repo.clojars.org) there is a nice web interface with a search box, and if I enter "arctype" (without the double quotes) and do a search on that, it finds arctype/service, but not arctype/service.jose, probably because arctype/service.jose was not published on the clojars.org site.  Or, if it was, someone decided to remove it.  Removing published things is fairly uncommon, so my guess is that if arctype/service.jose ever existed, it might have only been published on the repo.enonic.com site.

Is your project open source?  Published on Github.com or a similar site where others can get a copy and try it out?  If yes, including that in your question would help others see if they get the same error you do.

If the project you are working with is not open source, then hopefully someone more familiar with the particular errors you are seeing than I am will answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I can't really share the whole project but, I did add the project.clj to a new public repo I made so you can see the config in project.clj. Here is the link: https://github.com/TravSLockett/clojure-config-issue
Let me know if you have issues accessing it.

Comment: @travisconfused This is sorta unresolvable. You have a project which depends on some artifact nobody knows where to find. You can't fix that except by finding out where the artifact is.

Comment: @amalloy yes it makes sense from a fundamental standpoint. I don't have a lot of clue because I heritated the project. In that case, may I ask if you know what arctype service jose is ? or specifically jose? I looked it up and found that it could be "Javascript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE)". Is this a common thing in java? I think i might try to find out what that thing is first and then see if it still exists anymore. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @amalloy actually update, just found out that service.jose is not from the community repo, its from a different repo. Its from here: https://github.com/arctype-co/service.jose, my question is, how can I reference the dependencies of "arctype:service.jose" to go to aboved url in project.clj? Thanks again!

Comment: You can either figure out what maven repo they published this artifact to, or else publish it yourself (to a different groupid) based on their source files. But since they don't publish it with any license file attached, it might be tricky to figure out your legal options.

Comment: @amalloy gotcha. Assuming license is not an issue. Is there a way I can add the repo address where the artifact is in project.clj, and when it loads that dependency, it could automatically go to that repo instead of the community repo to look for it? Meaning, instead of trying to add the artifact to the community repo, refer it to a separate repo for the artifact. Probably a bad practice.. Thanks!

Comment: If you knew what repository it is published to, you could just add that to your :repositories key in project.clj. But you don't: you only know where to find the source on github. Maven dependency reduction does not interact with github in any way.

Comment: @amalloy Understood. Just 2 quick follow up questions, it is usually a bad practice to have personal repo dependency in the project right? If so, I see 3 possible ways of going about it, the first one is what you suggested, to try to publish it to maven or clojar.
The second one would be implementing that dependency in my own project as a separate class for it to be accessible.
The third one would be finding an alternative to that dependency that is published to clojar or maven.
Am I wrong in any of the 3 possible solutions?